# Detect Last Drawn Shape

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm creating a game in C++ using SFML but I ran into an issue with moving shapes using the mouse.

I am drawing multiple shapes, each shape has it's own handle input method and when I handle the window event, I loop over a vector array and call the handle input method of each shape.

```
void Plank::HandleInput(sf::Event event)
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
    {
        if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Button::Left)
        {
            m_MouseHold = true;
            std::cout << "Left Press\n";
        }

        if (m_Shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_Game->m_Window))))
        {
            std::cout << "In Bounds\n";
            m_MoveShape = true;
        }
        break;
    }

    case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
    {
        m_MouseHold = false;
        m_MoveShape = false;
        break;
    }

    case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
    {
        if (m_MoveShape)
        {
            std::cout << "Move Shape\n";
            m_Shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_Game->m_Window)));
        }
        break;
    }

    default: break;
    }
}
```

The issue is that if two shapes overlap and you click on where the shapes intersect you can move both shapes.

I want to only be able to move the shape which is on top, but I couldn't figure out how after some thinking and research.

Comment: There is no way that I know of to get this information through SFML, so you will have to keep track of it yourself.  If you have defined a standard order in which to draw your shapes, then the reverse of that will tell you what was drawn most recently.  For example, if you store a vector of shapes and simply draw by iterating over that vector, then you can iterate in reverse to determine which shape to grab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did something similar to what you said @0x5453

In my window poll event I looped over my array of shapes and stored the array position of the shape which contained my mouse in its global bounds first. Then from there on I simply moved the shape in the array position I had noted.

```
for (size_t i = m_PlankObjects.size(); i-- > 0;)
{
    if (m_PlankObjects[i].m_Shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_Game->m_Window))))
    {
        selectedObject = i;
        break;
    }
}
```